# numpy 3d array: normalising columns in the last dimension while filtering specific rows in the last dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I've been trying to solve this problem for a while and can't figure it out.

I need to normalise the values inside a ( M , N , 2 ) numpy array column by column (IE: Normalise [ : , : , 0 ] and [ : , : , 1 ] separately).

The additional challenge is that I have to ignore all the "rows" where the pair-values are BOTH 0. (IE: where [ m , n , : ] == [ 0 , 0 ])

The following is the example input/output:

input:

```
np.array([[[1, 2],
           [2, 3],
           [5, 4]],

          [[0, 0],
           [1, 2],
           [3, 0]],

          [[0, 0],
           [0, 0],
           [0, 3]],

          [[1, 7],
           [-3, 3],
           [2, 4]]])
```

output:

```
np.array([[[0.5, 0.2857..],
           [0.625, 0.4285..],
           [1, 0.5714..]],

          [[0, 0],
           [0.5, 0.2857],
           [0.75, 0]],

          [[0, 0],
           [0, 0],
           [0.375, 0.4285]],

          [[0.5, 1],
           [0, 0.4285],
           [0.625, 0.5714]]])
```

I have to apply this function over quite a lot of rows ~100MB
Thanks in advance

PS: the norm formula (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you have tried? Is it not working specifically because of the large dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100MB isn't so large, so maybe simply masking out the 'rows' you need to ignore would suffice:

```
arr = arr.astype(np.float64)
zero = (arr == 0).all(axis=2)
keep = arr[~zero]
low, high = keep.min(axis=0), keep.max(axis=0)
arr[~zero] = (keep - low) / (high - low)
```

gives me

```
In [55]: arr
Out[55]: 
array([[[0.5       , 0.28571429],
        [0.625     , 0.42857143],
        [1.        , 0.57142857]],

       [[0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.5       , 0.28571429],
        [0.75      , 0.        ]],

       [[0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.375     , 0.42857143]],

       [[0.5       , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.42857143],
        [0.625     , 0.57142857]]])
```